# Flutter - Using common attributes across pages

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm writing a Flutter app and planning to use GetX for state management (amongst other things). The common design pattern seems to be to use one dart file per view (screen) and for each view to have its own associated controller file.

However, what is the best approach when you have state that isn't just used within a single screen, but instead needs to be shared across screens? It seems wrong to import controllers from one view into the view or controller for another screen. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Provider package to share the state between multiple widgets? https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Thanks. I thought GetX was supposed to replace the need for using Providers and simplify state management. Do I need to use a combination of Providers and GetX?

Comment: Tbh I’ve never used GetX and I think you can share the state with Provider package as you wish. I’m not saying GetX is not good for this purpose but I don’t have any experience with it

Comment: Thanks for your help @Morez

Answer (score 0):

You can use **GetxService**: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/documentation/get_state_manager/latest/get_state_manager/GetxService-class.html

As it says: *Unlike GetxController, which serves to control events on each of its pages, GetxService is not automatically disposed (nor can be removed with Get.delete()). It is ideal for situations where, once started, that service will remain in memory, such as Auth control for example. Only way to remove it is Get.reset().*